# Can't target CSS selectors which work in dev tools

Tags: html, css, padding, lightbox

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLgsp.jpg)

Hello guys, I'm trying to remove the padding from a lightbox in my page builder. When I go into Chrome inspector and add attribute of:

```
style="padding: 0;"
```

The change appears in the screen how I'd expect it. However, when I copy the HTLM selectors and apply this CSS (at the bottom of the stylesheet), nothing happens. Here's my CSS, please note I've tried with and without spaces between the classes (because I'm new to this). Update: adding !important fixed it.

```
.fl-node-58c7610c1222e.fl-button-lightbox-content {
    padding: 0;
}
```

When I right click and select 'copy selectors,' I get this ID on the clipboard which I can't see in the HTML:

```
#yui_3_5_1_1_1489587619181_788
```

Because of this mysterious ID I've also tried the following CSS, with and without spaces between the classes/ID:

```
.fl-node-58c7610c1222e.fl-button-lightbox-content#yui_3_5_1_1_1489587619181_788 {
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Still, no joy. Could somebody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the HTML as well please? The selectors look very strange.

Comment: Did you try   `padding: 0px;` ?

Comment: Are you sure that's padding not margin?

Comment: Can we get a link to live example?

Comment: sure, link is:

http://www.stagehypnosisuniversity.com , password is lemon.

Strange selectors because it's a page builder. @mayersdesign yes it's padding as I changed it in chrome inspector

Comment: @KobyDouek you can skip units when it's 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it just requires:

```
.fl-node-58c7610c1222e.fl-button-lightbox-content {padding: 0 !important}
```

Comment: Great. I think your theme has complex stylesheets...as most of them do. The !important is the easiest/surefire way to trump them. Please accept the answer if it solved it for you :)